# How to detect generic type passed to an interface?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to allow the classes implementing the interface pass generic type parameter to a method. But the compiler is not able to detect the type and below code doesn't work.

```kotlin
interface Handler<T> {
    fun execute(): T
    fun process(data: T)
}

class StringHandler : Handler<String> {
    override fun execute(): String {
        //
    }

    override fun process(data: String) {
        //
    }

}

class IntHandler : Handler<Int> {
    override fun execute(): Int {
        //
    }

    override fun process(data: Int) {
        //
    }

}

fun main() {
    val handler by lazy {
        if (true) {
            StringHandler()
        } else {
            IntHandler()
        }
    }

    val data = handler.execute()
    handler.process(data)
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in the way you want to.

Comment: You might be able to do something with `when` and relying on smart casting, but that is essentially doing a series instance-of checks and should really only ever be done with sealed types. But otherwise, Louis is correct.

Comment: @Slaw Right, but this just won't scale well as more methods are added to the interface. I am considering losing out on the type and doing force cast in the classes.

Comment: @LouisWasserman What would be the best way to approach this? I am open to restructuring it as long as we can preserve types

Comment: I would question why you need any of this.  You should _know_ what types are present, what the meaning of a value of that type is, and what sorts of handlers are appropriate to handle it, in any application.  Why would you need one `handler` that can handle both `""` and 42?

Comment: @LouisWasserman you are correct I know the types but only inside of classes. Classes can perform operation `exectute()` on different data which is why in the interface I am not using Any. I have updated the code. Basically Handler is performing some operation and then processing it. I wanted to abstract these methods in the interface. You are correct I do not need a handler that can process different types but which handler to use us decided on runtime.

Comment: Instead of generics I think a sealed type or enum is more appropriate for a couple reasons. 1. Generics are erased at runtime. They can't be inspected at runtime. 2. To determine the type at runtime, you'll have to do `is` checks, which are often a code smell when used with non-sealed types. They're a warning sign of tight coupling and poor scalability.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Could you help me with how the implementation would look like with sealed types?

Comment: Not all that different except you use the sealed type's classes as wrappers around your data. But I'm not sure exactly what you are implying with that `by lazy` example. How are you determining which type of handler you need? It looks like it's producing its own data to operate on.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Lazy initialization can be ignored. Determining which handler to use is based on an enum

Comment: If you already have an enum and are using it to choose your handler, then isn't your problem already solved? I'm not sure which piece of the solution you're looking for help with.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have an enum but which would tell me which handler to use but then I need to call some common methods on it which otherwise would lead to another if else ladder.

Comment: Generics will help you with that part, just not with selecting the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
interface Handler<T> {
    companion object {
        private val intHandler by lazy { IntHandler() }
        private val stringHandler by lazy { StringHandler() }
        fun <T> process(data: T) {
            when (data) {
                is Int -> intHandler.execute(data)
                is String -> stringHandler.execute(data)
            }
        }
    }

    fun execute(data: T)
}

class StringHandler : Handler<String> {
    override fun execute(data: String) {
        // ...
    }
}

class IntHandler : Handler<Int> {
    override fun execute(data: Int) {
        // ...
    }
}

fun main() {
    Handler.process("")
    Handler.process(1)
}
```